# for prop array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

Hi I am trying to perform a loop, through an array of objects and perform a find and replace for each property. Below is an example of what each object looks like and the for statement that is giving me trouble

```
specialAdsArray.push({dogID:[dataRange[i][0],"[dogID]"], 
              dogName:[dataRange[i][1],"[dogName]"] 
              })



  for (var prop in specialAdsArray[i]) {
    if (specialAdsArray[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      adPiecesArrayCopy[j]=  adPiecesArrayCopy[j].content.replace(adPiecesArrayCopy[i].prop[0],adPiecesArrayCopy[i].prop[1])
 }
}
```

Once I get to this step though where I actually go through to do the actual find and replace. The variable prop is not acting as the array I thought it would represent. and I'm getting: "

**TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 89, file "Try 3")**

How do I access theses sub-arrays that are assigned to each property.

Comment: please add the data as well.

Comment: where is `i` defined?

Comment: `prop` is a dynamic property name, so you should not write `.prop` (which looks for a property called "prop"), but `[prop]`.

Comment: @trincot this was marked as duplicated but thank you for the help that was answer! I mixed up an array int the data provided but once I changed the final part to [i][prop][1] and [i][prop][0] it works!